# How to select data from an array to graph

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of nine columns and over 5 million rows for some experimental data about stars.

The index numbers of the Columns are:

0 Mass
1 Age
2 Timestep
3 Metallicity
4 Effective temperature
5 Luminosity
6 log surface gravity
7 Radius
8 Base of outermost convective layer.

I would like to plot in Python Luminosity against Temperature for just those stars in certain mass ranges.

Rather than iterate over the array, I would like to use implicit array indexing which I am told is faster?

I can plot the entire Mass range by pulling the entire column for Luminosity, and the entire column for Temperature, and that works OK, but now I would like to do separate plots for different Mass ranges, and that's where I am stuck.

If there is another solution that would work with a large file size, that would be great.  It doesn't matter how to solve the problem, I just want to learn how to select key bits of data from the data array.

Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
path="C://///.filename.txt"
mesa_data=np.loadtxt(path)
print(mesa_data.shape)
print(mesa_data)
luminosity = mesa_data[:,5]
teff = mesa_data[:,4]
plt.plot(teff,luminosity,'go')
plt.xlim(10000, 0)  # decreasing Temperature
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.ylabel('Luminosity (Solar Units)')
plt.title('HR Diagram for MESA model')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution of sorts.

I created a Boolean array, and then used that to index the sliced arrays I had extracted from the data.

It doesn't really do what I would like it to do.  I can create an array of Booleans by using the code immediately below, but I get errors if I set by column to equal a range in be

```
m_half = mesa_data[:,0] < 0.501 and > 0.499
```

I get the error message.

"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

I am going to investigate the suggested solutions, but is there a better approach.  I feel like I am over complicating something that might be quite simple?

I would like to interrogate my data table to get all types of combinations out of it, but at the moment I only know how to do it for values less than a certain parameter, or of course greater.

Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
path="data.txt"
mesa_data=np.loadtxt(path)
print(mesa_data.shape)
print(mesa_data)
luminosity = mesa_data[:,5]   #Use implicit array indexing to slice the Luminosity values
teff = mesa_data[:,4]         #Use implicit array indexing to slice the Temperature values
m_half = mesa_data[:,0] < 0.501   #Create a Boolean Array for those Masses in a certain range
l_half = luminosity[m_half]      #Use Boolean to create a new data range of luminosities for those stars in mass range
teff_half = teff[m_half]           #Use Boolean to create a new data range of temperatures for those stars in mass range

plt.subplot (2,1,1)
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
plt.plot(teff,luminosity,'go')
plt.xlim(10000, 0)  # decreasing Temperature
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.ylabel('Luminosity (Solar Units)')
plt.title('HR Diagram for MESA model over all Masses')
plt.subplot (2,1,2)
plt.plot(teff_half,l_half,'go')
plt.xlim(4500, 3000)  # decreasing Temperature
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.ylabel('Luminosity (Solar Units)')
plt.title('HR Diagram for MESA model for 0.5 Solar Mass units')

plt.savefig ("HR_All.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```